# Javascript interpreter for Ecmascript 6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, rhino

What javascript interpreters suppport Ecmascript6? Currently rhino does not support es6  what are the alternatives?

Comment: Have you used google to search for alternatives to Rhino?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a binary question (support ES6 or not).  There's no interpreter that supports all of ES6 bug-free, but there are many that support much of it.  Here's a [giant ES6 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) that covers a lot of interpreters and you can see which has the features you most want.  And, there's [another feature table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/) for some features beyond that.

I know from experience that you can use a lot of ES6 features in latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Nodejs depending upon what type of environment you are looking for.